how to reduce RAM used by wingpanel?
wingpanel uses 1.5 gigabyte of RAM on my computer see the first row on the top of this screenshot: 
I have only a few software running (browser, e-mail software, small calculation sheet) and the wingpanel is taking most of the available RAM.

Can you help me understanding what wingpanel is doing with all this
RAM quantity?
Can you give me advices on how to reduce this RAM
consumption for wingpanel?

Many thanks in advance.

Elementary OS 6.1 Jolnir

Careful, "memory" does not always refer to RAM. This can include buffers, shared libraries, and the like. Generally, systems will try to keep as much in memory as it can so that the system operates as quickly as possible. If you are running an application that really needs as much physical RAM as possible, the OS will automatically manage the need, using swap and other techniques to ensure the system remains performant.
